# What's the difference between #import <Library/Library.h> and #import <Library.h> using CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I've seen guides on CocoaPods that recommend importing a needed pod's library header like this:

```
#import <Library/Library.h>
```

Where `Library` is the name of the library (e.g. `#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>`).

I've also seen guides that recommend importing a needed pod's library header like this:

```
#import <Library.h>
```

(e.g. `#import <AFNetworking.h>`)

Both methods compile and seem to work.

What's the difference and which should be used?

Comment: is it possible that a user may define a custom class called AFNetworking and then in order to distinguish which AFNetworking.h to use there is a need to put it like AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h ... I am no expert on this topic but your question is interesting +1

Comment: Here is some useful insight to your question - http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/01/helping-xcode-find-library-headers/

Comment: @SamBudda, great link. Of particular interest, `<path/header.h> with angle brackets – these are meant for system or “global” includes.` Since the file is actually within the Xcode `workspace` (a.k.a., global to the project being built) `<header.h>` OR `<library/header.h>` works. At least, this is my take away from it. Right?

Comment: yup, that's what I gather from it.

Comment: For what's worth, if the preprocessor finds unqualified headers with `import <Library.h>`, the Pods setup is wrong. This can result in conflicting headers, for example lib A and lib B have a header with the same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either way works fine if the header being imported is unique. But if you have a header with the same name in two different third party libraries, it gets ambiguous, and you will need to specify which one you want.

Generally, it's best to specify the library name so that this case won't happen, but also because it's immediately apparent to somebody reading your code what library that header file is a part of, since it's not always apparent based on the header name.

Comment: So, the take away is: use `<library/header.h>` to be clear to your dev readers and avoid duplicate name conflicts. Thanks, Gavin!

Comment: @JRG-Developer Yes, it's important to remember that from a library "XYZ", you're not always importing a header named "XYZ.h". Sometimes it might be "blah.h", so someone else won't intuitively know that `#import <blah.h>` belongs to library "XYZ". But `#import <XYZ/blah.h>` makes it immediately clear, and also differentiates it from `#import <ABC/blah.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

Actualy:

```
#import <Library/Library.h>
```

is different from:

```
#import <Library.h>
```

In first case you tell the preprocessor, that there is a directory in HEADER_SEARCH_PATH, that contains a directory named 'Library' and there is a file 'Library.h' in that directory.
In second case preprocessor assumes that it can find 'Library.h' in a HEADER_SEARCH_PATH directly.
If both directories are in HEADER_SEARCH_PATH - there is no difference between this two.
Some CocoaPods specify in specs

```
 s.header_mappings_dir = 'SomeFolderWhereSourcesPlaced'
```

In this case

```
A directory from where to preserve the folder structure for the headers files. If not provided the headers files are flattened.
```

So, if there is header_mappings_dir specified - full paths are required because pod install will only point to root directory where it puts headers.